# Try and Except. I am trying to implement a grading score but keep on getting except print as an output

Tags: python, try-catch, except

```py
score = input('Enter score:')
try:
    if score >= 0.9 and score < 1.0:
        print("Grade is A")
    else:
        if score >= 0.8 and score < 0.9:
            print("Grade is B")
        else:
            if score >= 0.7 and score < 0.8:
                print("Grade is C")
            else:
                if score >=0.6 and score < 0.7:
                    print("Grade is D")
                else:
                    if score <  0.6 and score <=0.0:
                        print("Grade is F")
except:
    print('bad score')
```

I have been trying to write a program where the score exists between 0.0 and 1.0 and grades are based on score. I have an exception in case the user insert any other value or text other range of scores which lies between 1.0 and 0.0.

Comment: can this be properly formatted?

Comment: Python 2 or python 3? The input function is probably throwing your error if you are in python2

Comment: I am using python version 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the built-in function to show us code fragments. Otherwise, we can't really help you.
I think that the problem with your code is that you have multiple else statements on the same layer. It is only possible to have one else statement per if statement on the same layer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python 3, `input()` returns data type of `String` so when you ask the question `score >= 0.9`, you are asking `"1" >= 0.9` (assuming user typed `1`). Python doesn't recognize `"1" >= 0.9` so it errors out, and goes to the except clause.

You need to change the data type that the user types into a `float` or `integer` using a technique called 'Casting'. For example `float("0.95")` returns `0.95`, which can be compared with `0.9`.

PS. You can type in lines of code with the backtick ` (above the `TAB` or beside the `1` on your keyboard. Otherwise, you can highlight all your code and click on "Code" in the Stack Overflow editor, which will convert it to easy-to-read code for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    score = float(input('Enter score:'))
    if score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0: 
        print("Grade is A") 
    elif score >= 0.8 and score < 0.9: 
            print("Grade is B")
    elif score >= 0.7 and score < 0.8: 
            print("Grade is C") 
    elif score >=0.6 and score < 0.7: 
            print("Grade is D") 
    else: 
        print("Grade is F") 
except: 
    print('bad score')
```

Comment: I tried this approach, the problem with this approach is that it will provide me grades for scores between 0.1 and 1.0 but if I enter "text" as input then it won't give me an except error. In fact, it displays a syntax error

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'test' `

Comment: Then please put "score = float(input('Enter score:'))" inside the try block. If we enter the text it goes to except block and print as bad score. I've modified the above code as per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

please provide code in proper format. Below is one of the similar code which will work
Issue is with [input() function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) so you need to change data type using casting

```
score = float(input('Enter score:') )
try: 
    if score >= 0.9 and score < 1.0:
        print("Grade is A") 
    else: 
        if score >= 0.8 and score < 0.9: 
            print("Grade is B") 
        else: 
            if score >= 0.7 and score < 0.8:
                print("Grade is C") 
            else: 
                if score >=0.6 and score < 0.7:
                    print("Grade is D") 
                else: 
                    if score < 0.6 and score <=0.0:     
                        print("Grade is F") 
except: 
    print('bad score')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:    
    score=float(input("Enter number: "))
    if (score>=0.9) and (score <=1.0):
        print('Grade is A')
    elif (score>=0.8) and (score <0.9):
        print('Grade is B')
    elif (score>=0.7) and (score <0.8):
        print('Grade is C')
    elif (score>=0.6) and (score <0.7):
        print('Grade is D')
    elif (score<0.6) and (score >=0.0):
        print('Grade is F')
    else:
        print ("Bad score")
except:
    print("This is not a number")
```